# About how many people in the world speak English as a lingua Franca?

Tags: language-formation

Does anyone know of any reliable sources where I can find an estimated number or percentage of people in the world who now speak English as a lingua franca? I've read that anywhere from 1 1/2 to 2 billion people  can understand or use English to some extent, but this source wasn't very reliable.

Comment: My guess is somewhat *more* than 2 billion people would understand the specific word ***okay***. But that doesn't imply they could conduct any sort of meaningful conversation in English. I suspect the total number of *native* Anglophones is actually less than the population of the USA today.

Comment: Though the nominal definitions are different, you could take 'people who use ENglish as a lingua franca' to be the same as 'pepole who speak English not as a native language'. Then look at [the L2 column for English in the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers). You can judge its reliability.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _Okay_ may have originated in English, but it an integral part now of so many languages, that the word itself must be classified as multilingual. So it's not the best word to use as an example—it's simply part of people's own languages, even if they've never learnt a single word of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *Ethnologue*, the lower bound would be 840 million speakers of English as a first or second language ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers)).  Degree of proficiency is not specifically addressed, nor is the count of speakers of English as a third/fourth/etc. language. I suspect the actual number is much higher if one is generous in defining "speaking English."